# ionic4 sqlite No data available

Tags: sqlite

I use ionic4 + angular8 + @ionic-native/sqlite/ngx

You can insert success. the number of data tables taken is correct, but no data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMITa.png)
What's the problem  thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to read data like this

```
 this.sqlite.create({name: 'myapp.db',  location: 'default'}).then((db : SQLiteObject) => {
     db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM table_name where id=?', [id]).then((data) => {
            let results = []
            for (let i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
                let item = data.rows.item(i);
                results.push(item);
            }
            console.log(results)
        }).catch(e => console.log(e));
    }).catch(e => console.log('sqlite error',e))
```

You will get all the data in **results**